# checking node name with attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

how to find if a node exists with the attribute value using xslt?

suppose if my xml like this

```
<root>
 <sub>
    <p>text</p>
   <title id='id1-num-444'>text</title>
    <p>text</p>  
   <title id='id1-str-aaa'>text</title>
    <p>text</p>  
   <title id='id1-num-333'>text</title> 
    <p>text</p>  
 </sub>
</root>
```

i used the following xsl

```
<xsl:template match ="sub">

  ....some tags...

  <xsl:if test ="contains(name(), 'title[@id='id1-num']')">
  <xsl:call-template name ="title"></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The if condition need to check till num, it shouldn't consider anything after num.
Thanks.

Comment: John, you may be interested in a shorter and more accurate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test on part of an attribute value, you need to use `contains()`, but of course, not quite the way you did.

Assuming, as Sean Durkin said, that your focus is on a candidate title element,

```
<xsl:if test ="contains(self::title/@id,'id1-num')">
    <xsl:call-template name ="title"></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

or the slightly less explicit

```
<xsl:if test ="contains(@id,'id1-num')">
    <xsl:call-template name ="title"></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

**A shorter and more precise solution is to use the standard XPath function [`starts-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-starts-with)**:

```
starts-with(@id, 'id1-num')
```

So, your code fragment becomes:

```
<xsl:if test="starts-with(@id, 'id1-num')">
   <xsl:call-template name ="title"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

We need a bit more context to understand what you want, but perhaps you want to match on a template rule like so? ...

```
<xsl:template match="title[@id='id1-num']">
  ... contents go here ...
</xsl:template>
```

If it needs to be a test within a sequence constructor, and the focus item is a candidate title element, then perhaps? ...

```
<xsl:if test ="self::title[@id='id1-num']">
  <xsl:call-template name ="title"></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

In the above, the test will pass if and only if:

1. The focus item is an element named title;
2. and it has an attribute id with value 'id1-num'

Comment: sorry i can't able to use template, i need to do by using some other way like if condition  or others because in my original xml it's come under a template. my original xml is too big i can't able to post that.